# How to get multiples of 100 rounded to the nearest thousand

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and I'm trying to come up with a for loop (or any other method) that can return multiples of 100 but rounded to the nearest thousand, here's what I have right now:

```
huneds = [h * 100 for h in range(1,50)]
    
for r in huneds:
    if r % 3 == float:
        print(r)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: every number in `huneds` is a multiple of `100`. as you multiply them all by `100`. What exactly are you after?

Answer (score 2):

The built-in [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function will accept a negative number that you can use to round to thousands:

```
for r in huneds:
    print(round(r, -3))
```

Which prints:

```
0
0
0
0
0
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
2000

...

4000
4000
5000
5000
5000
5000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see use

```
for n in range(0,2500,100):
  print(n, ' -> ',1000 * round(n / 1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

For any number `m`, `m` is a multiple of `n` if the remainder of `n / m` is `0`. I.e. `n % m == 0` or in your case; `r % 100 == 0`, as the modulus operator (`%`) returns the remainder of a division. Use:

```
for r in huneds:
    if r % 100 == 0:
        print(r)
```

But every number is already a multiple of `100`, as you multiplied all of them by `100`.

You may be after something like:

```
# Range uses (start, stop, step) params
# print(list(range(0, 200, 10))) --> [0, 10, 20, ... 170, 180, 190]

for r in range(0, 200, 10):
    if r % 100 == 0 and r != 0:
        print(r)
```

Outputs

```
100
```

But you would like to round to the nearest `1000`. The `round()` function can do that.

```
for r in range(0, 2000, 10):
    if r % 100 == 0 and r != 0:
        print(f"{r} | {round(r, -3)}")
```

```
100 | 0
200 | 0
300 | 0
400 | 0
500 | 0
600 | 1000
700 | 1000
800 | 1000
...
```

- The `f` string does the same as `r + ' | ' + round(r, -3)`

  - This shows the number that is a multiple of `100` which is `r`, and then it rounded to the nearest `1000`
- `round()`'s second argument is the amount of digits to round too, as we are going to the nearest `1000`, we use `-3` as you are going on the left side of the decimal

---

I suggest having a read of:

> https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

And I highly reccomend: [this site (python principles)](https://pythonprinciples.com/lessons/) for learning python. Pro membership is currently free

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this,

```
list(map(lambda x: round(x/1000) * 1000, huneds))
```

It'll return you a list of rounded values for all the items of the list `huneds`.

Comment: You need to round to nearest `1000`. use `round(x, -3)` -> `list(map(lambda x: round(x, -3), huneds))`

Comment: Oh yh that too.